# How to use http subscribe with rxjs map to fetch two arrays of objects

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, rxjs

I've the following arrays of objects returned from the backend:

```
Array(object1):
[{"record_id":"1", "local_TimeStamp":"16:00:00", "country":"USA"},
 {"record_id":"2", "local_TimeStamp":"17:00:00", "country":"Japan"},
 {"record_id":"3", "local_TimeStamp":"17:00:00", "country":"Korea"},
 {"record_id":"4", "local_TimeStamp":"15:00:00", "country":"Thailand"},
 {"record_id":"5", "local_TimeStamp":"16:00:00", "country":"China"}]
Array(object2): 
 [{"record_id":"100", "Brand_Name":"Swire",   "Shippment-type":"Air"},
  {"record_id":"101", "Brand_Name":"Toshiba", "Shippment-type":"Ground"},
  {"record_id":"102", "Brand_Name":"RiUP",    "Shippment-type":"Special"},
  {"record_id":"103", "Brand_Name":"Lenovo",  "Shippment-type":"Local"},
  {"record_id":"104", "Brand_Name":"TopCon",  "Shippment-type":"Ground"}]
```

I tried to fetch these two http returned arrays into two local arrays but fail. Here is my code:

```
shippmentProvider ts file:
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
constructor(private http: HttpClient) {};

getBackEndService()
 {return this.http.get("http://local:8080/shippment.dat/")}
```

//

```
view ts file:
this.shippmentProvider.getBackEndService().map((data: any[]) => 
{ let localArray: any[] = data[0];
  let localArray1: any[] = data[1];
})
.subscribe(localArray => console.log(localArray))
.subscribe(localArray1 => console.log(localArray1));
```

Error: {error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token [ in JSON at position 6 at JSON.parse....}

It seems that the above code couldn't fetch the second array objects.  Please help !

Amendment:
With the advice from Fateh Mohamed, I'd modified the code as follow; however, the console.log seems never executed.  Any ideas?

view ts file:

```
import { Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';

subscription: Subscription;
localArray: Observable<Array<any>>;
localArray1: Observable<Array<any>>;

constructor(private http: HttpClient) {};

this.shippmentProvider.getBackEndService().map((data:Observable<Array<any>>) =>
 {
 this.localArray = data[0]; this.localArray1 = data[1];

 const Obs = Observable.combineLatest(this.localArray, this.localArray1,
 (array1, array2) => ({ array1, array2}));

 this.subscription = Obs.subscribe((arrays) => {
 console.log(arrays.array1);
 console.log(arrays.array2);
});
```

No errors but no console.log response neither!

Comment: what is the returned JSON interface? `{ object1: any[]; object2: any[] }` ?

Comment: The Angular http client expects the response to be in JSON format, whilst you seem to expect an Array. You can request non-json data as describe here: https://angular.io/guide/http#requesting-non-json-data

Comment: If I omitted the let localArray: any[] = data[0];
  let localArray1: any[] = data[1]; and the map operation and just subscibe it, it works with one array object.  But if the backend returned two or more arrays.  I don't know how to handle them.  Please advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can create 2 Observables for each result and use combineLatest, that way you can subscribe only once

```
const Obs = Observable.combineLatest(array1Observable, array2Observable,
        (array1, array2) => ({ array1, array2}));

this.subscription = Obs.subscribe((arrays) => {
  console.log(arrays.array1);
  console.log(arrays.array2);
 })
```

here is the final file

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/combineLatest';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  subscription: Subscription;
  array1Obs = Observable.of(
    [{"record_id":"1", "local_TimeStamp":"16:00:00", "country":"USA"},
     {"record_id":"2", "local_TimeStamp":"17:00:00", "country":"Japan"},
     {"record_id":"3", "local_TimeStamp":"17:00:00", "country":"Korea"},
     {"record_id":"4", "local_TimeStamp":"15:00:00", "country":"Thailand"},
     {"record_id":"5", "local_TimeStamp":"16:00:00", "country":"China"}]);
  array2Obs = Observable.of(
    [{"record_id":"100", "Brand_Name":"Swire",   "Shippment-type":"Air"},
     {"record_id":"101", "Brand_Name":"Toshiba", "Shippment-type":"Ground"},
     {"record_id":"102", "Brand_Name":"RiUP",    "Shippment-
 type":"Special"},
 {"record_id":"103", "Brand_Name":"Lenovo",  "Shippment-type":"Local"},
 {"record_id":"104", "Brand_Name":"TopCon",  "Shippment-type":"Ground"}]);

  ngOnInit() {
   const Obs = Observable.combineLatest(this.array1Obs, this.array2Obs,
     (array1, array2) => ({ array1, array2}));

   this.subscription = Obs.subscribe((arrays) => {
     console.log(arrays.array1);
     console.log(arrays.array2);
   })    
  }
 }
```

Comment: I modified the code as follow but the console.log didn't executed.  Any ideas? import { Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';

import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';  (Oops, I'll post again !)

Comment: does console.log show undefined ? did you put the code inside ngOnInit?

Comment: No. I didn't put them inside the ngOnInit, I call it.

Comment: i've updated the answer with final solution, i can see the 2 arrays value in my console

Comment: you have an error right there, you are setting an array to an observable of array here this.localArray = data[0]; this.localArray1 = data[1]; , it should be this.localArray = Observable.of(data[0]); this.localArray1 = Observable.of(data[1]);

Comment: Might I ask how to use the map function together with the Observable.of as it's not a constant array?

Comment: Will array1Obs = Observable.of(data[0]) OK?

Comment: yes it's ok and combineLatest will will be more interesting when you have observable from multiple sources

Comment: It still didn't return any console.log.  I think the problem might be because I'm using the http get and it returns a observable so without using .subscribe that observable will never be activated so the map will never take place which will put the observable into two arrays...any thoughts?

Comment: Should it be this.shippmentProvider.getBackEndService().subscribe(() => { your code here   }

Comment: this.shippmentProvider.getBackEndService().map((data : Observable<Array<any>>) => {
     this.localArray = Observable.of(data[0]);
     this.localArray1 = Observable.of(data[1]);
    
const Obs = Observable.combineLatest(this.localArray, this.localArray1,
      (array1, array2) => ({ array1, array2}));
   
this.subscription = Obs.subscribe((arrays) => {
console.log(arrays.array1);
console.log(arrays.array2);
}); // No console.log displayed